# How do the viral loads of vaccinated and unvaccinated asymptomatic, and symptomatic individuals differ for COVID-19?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, disease-transmission, infectious-diseases

I'm searching for information regarding the above question, but I seem to keep finding conflicting information. [Some articles say that asymptomatic people have higher viral loads than symptomatic people](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7685188/), [some say that they have the same viral loads](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/34287354/#:%7E:text=Based%20on%20real%2Dtime%20RT,the%20maintenance%20of%20the%20pandemic.), [while others say they have lower viral loads](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32437933/). [Some also say that vaccinated and unvaccinated people have similar viral loads](https://www.medrxiv.org/content/10.1101/2021.07.31.21261387v1), [while others say that vaccinated people have lower viral loads](https://www.webmd.com/vaccines/covid-19-vaccine/news/20210702/study-says-vaccinated-people-who-get-covid-carry-less-virus).

I don't have the necessary expertise to filter out which studies are untrustworthy, but I have my doubts that all of them are likely to be true at the same time.

Comment: Can you cite the sources you're referring to?

Comment: @BryanKrause I have included some examples

Comment: I just read that although the viral loads may be comparable, the viruses expelled by those who have Covid-19 Anti-bodies in their system, (either from vaccination or from prior infection), are coated with those antibodies, and are therefore significantly less likely to cause symptomatic infection in others.

Comment: do you have a source?